# Very new to linux (fedora). Trying to streamline my login process for work

Tags: login, clipboard

I'm extremely new to both Linux and writing any sort of code.
I've been setting up my workstation on a Fedora OS. I'm trying to streamline my process as much as possible, but I've run into a couple problems which I've been able to solve. I need a one time password to log in to work, and the next challenge I've set for myself is to streamline receiving entering this OTP for easier access to my company's portal.

The process is simple: enter mobile number into application, receive OTP on phone and enter it to continue. I've set the program to launch on startup, now I'd just like a way to automatically paste my number into the application so that the OTP sends to my phone. Somewhere along the line, I'd like to be able to find a way to get the OTP to my workstation and then enter it automatically as well, but for now my focus is only to launch the program on start up and then have it send the OTP to my phone.

I can also use a link in chrome if that'll make it easier.

Comment: This very much depends on how the OTP receives the number. Are there CLI-options? It is a pure GUI that you need to find? You'llhave to add more details.

Comment: It's simply GIU from my understanding, as of now i literally just want to paste a pre-determined into the text box provided as soon as the application launches. i've experimented with having a text document containing the text that needs to be imported into the application's text box, I simply lack the experience to even know where to begin.

Comment: Speak to your local IT

Comment: GUIs can be tough to work with, but if you're lucky with a supported DE and your GUI has the right element focused, you could send keystrokes to the window containing the GUI using `xdotool type --window "$(xdotool search otp | head -1)" quit && xdotool key --window "$(xdotool search otp | head -1)" Enter'`, swapping `otp` for some of the text of the window in its title bar.